# Code stopped by every method then finally go to ngOnInit

Tags: angular

I have an angular 5 class and there are many methods.

```
export class App implements OnInit {
constructor() {
 // Called first time before the ngOnInit()
}

ngOnInit() {
 // Called after the constructor and called  after the first ngOnChanges() 
 }
 method_1() {
    //  ...
    console.log('1');
 }
 method_2() {
    //  ...
    console.log('2');
 }
 method_3() {
    //  ...
    console.log('3');
 }
 // many many
 method_25() {
    //  ...
    console.log('25');
 }
```

}

If I set breaking points in every method's signature and I found that it reached there. It just stopped on the signature line not inside. Finally the code reached `ngOnInit()`. I think that it should not behave in such way. It should go to `ngOnInit` first after the page is rendered then if I click a button or something else then the corresponding method is called.

I don't know where is wrong. I checked all the html and css file. But it seems okay. Is there any way to track the error?

**EDIT:**

I want some error handle service to inject into the constructor to catch this error.

Comment: Well, I guess I got downvoted because of not enough lines code. But  there are thousand lines. I want to a general catch error method to validate that kind of thing.

Comment: I suspect the downvote was due to lack of information. The question isn't clear at the moment. It'd help to have a minimal working example (eg. using Stackblitz).

Comment: I understand it but there is no quick way to create the working example because I don't know which direction should I go. I want some error handle service to inject into the constructor to catch this error.@MichaelD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The breakpoints get hit when the class's methods are parsed by your browser. Then, once the object is instantiated, you'll get constructor and `ngOnInit` breakpoints, only once each. To verify that, just add a `debugger` statement inside all your methods and check when the debugger stops.

Comment: It happened when I hit  F5 to refresh the page. So did you mean that it is okay all breakpoints get hit? And what did you mean `debugger`? Try and catch?

Comment: Yeah I meant that it's ok. Write  `debugger` inside your method. This will create breakpoint progmatically, inside the method (so when it gets called)